# Lightening the users accent colour

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, colors, windows-phone-8, themes

For a certain feature in my app I would like to retrieve the accent colour of the user, then lighten it by a certain amount, to give a paler version of the theme colour to use within the app.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your expected behavior when the user's theme color is white?

Comment: I meant accent colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following in your app.xaml.cs

```
private void setAccentResources()
{
    var accent = (Color)Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
    var accent80 = accent;
    var accent60 = accent;
    var accent40 = accent;
    var accent20 = accent;

    accent80.A = (byte)(accent.A * 0.8);
    accent60.A = (byte)(accent.A * 0.6);
    accent40.A = (byte)(accent.A * 0.4);
    accent20.A = (byte)(accent.A * 0.2);

    Resources.Add("PhoneAccentFullColor", new SolidColorBrush(accent));
    Resources.Add("PhoneAccent80Color", new SolidColorBrush(accent80));
    Resources.Add("PhoneAccent60Color", new SolidColorBrush(accent60));
    Resources.Add("PhoneAccent40Color", new SolidColorBrush(accent40));
    Resources.Add("PhoneAccent20Color", new SolidColorBrush(accent20));
}
```

You can then access it like:

```
 <control  Brush="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PhoneAccent40Color}" />
```

This adjusts the alpha channel so it will start to show anything that it overlays. If you want to adjust the color itself, you would adjust the R, G, and B values.